# How to change the Publishing Hyperlink icon image

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, site-column, file-icons

Is it possible to change the default images SharePoint 2010 Server uses to show next to the Publishing Hyperlink column type? This is enabled via the "Display link with icon" checkbox in the dialog box "Edit Hyerplink Properties". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use jQuery to swap out any instance of an image using something like the following:

```
$('[src~="theimage.jpg"]').attr('src','yourdesiredimage.jpg');
```

Comment: Very neat and clean. Thanks, James. I've got to see what image files are being dropped into the page by SharePoint.